# Can someone explaine to me this code?

Tags: c++

```
static void set_default_param(DPMTTICParam& param)
{

    param.overlap = 0.4;
    param.threshold = -0.5;
    param.lambda = 10;
    param.num_cells = 8;
}
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's unclear what you're asking. What is this code for? Where did you find it? What program is it being used in? As it stands, it looks like the best answer I can tell you is that it sets overlap, threshold, lambda, and number of cells in a parameter structure. Those values are hard coded though, and the function doesn't return a value, so again, without some *context*, I don't think anyone is going to be able to tell you what the code is used for.

Comment: What is this code for?  This code for object detection.........................Where did you find it? i found it here https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/packages/cv_tracker/nodes/dpm_ttic/dpm_ttic.cpp

Comment: What is this code for? This code For object Detection ..........Where did you find it? i found it here [link](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/packages/cv_tracker/nodes/dpm_ttic/dpm_ttic.cpp)

Comment: This should be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to belong to this software:
https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/lib/image/dpm_ttic/include/dpm_ttic/dpm_ttic.hpp

So - I assume that is just a case where someone is using that software, and it is showing how to set some default parameters.

I would suggest you ask the developers of that software directly though, if you want to use it.

Comment: I have already contacted the developers for more explanation, but i didn't get  any answer, so I'm trying to understand this code. In addition, ,this code for the object detection for the autonomous vehicle. Can you please give me any explanation if you could understand any of the code ? Click here for Link https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/packages/cv_tracker/nodes/dpm_ttic/dpm_ttic.cpp

Comment: I'll never know for sure, but if you're going to use that software you would use a piece of code like that to set default values for the sensitivity of the camera, and things like that. You would have to read through all the code on their page to **really** understand what these mean though... Not recommended if you're a beginner at this sort of programming, for example.

Comment: I'm a student at the University of Michigan, And I just would like to get some help from someone like you, if you could explain few line of code for me that will be very helpful.THANK YOU